# How to feed tensorflow image value of shape (3,3) into targets which has shape (?, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to feed a value of shape 3,3 into a tensor of shape (?, 2). My question is how do I reshape my (3,3) value so it is compatible with the latter.

Here is my main training loop:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    batches = dg.get_mini_batches(batchSize,(128,128), allchannel=False)
    for imgs ,labels in batches:
        imgs=np.divide(imgs, 255)
        error, sumOut, acu, steps,_ = sess.run([cost, summaryMerged, accuracy,global_step,optimizer],
                                        feed_dict={input_img: imgs, target_labels: labels})
        writer.add_summary(sumOut, steps)
        print("epoch=", epoch, "Total Samples Trained=", steps*batchSize, "err=", error, "accuracy=", acu)
        if steps % 100 == 0:
            print("Saving the mdl")
            saver.save(sess, mdl_save_path+mdl_name, global_step=steps)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/PycharmProjects/tf-foodar/tf-foodar-beta.py", line 87, in <module>
    feed_dict={input_img: imgs, target_labels: labels})
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda\envs\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda\envs\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1104, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3, 3) for Tensor 'Target/Targets:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

A tensor with shape `(3,3)` can't be reshaped (using `tf.reshape`) into a tensor with shape `(?,2)` where `?` is an unknown dimension and `2` is fixed.

This is because you have `3 x 3 = 9` elements and `9/2 = 4.5` is not an integer (4.5 is the computed value of the unknown dimension). Hence you can't create a new tensor with shape `(4.5, 2)`.

However, there's something wrong with your reasoning. Ask yourself: why I want to feed a network with data whose network is not able to accept?